# Android - apk file successfully exported but error when run

Tags: android, export, apk

There was no errors in the process and in the designated destination folder, the apk file is created. 
I dragged and dropped the apk file (after export) to my device and install it.
After installed, I run it, but it throws an error "Unfortunately, ....has stopped". 
When I dragged and dropped the apk file in the BIN folder of project folder, install and run, it was no errors.
Please help me!!! 
Thanks a lot

Comment: I had faced same issue, and I again **cleaned and build project**, recreated apk, it worked fine. Try that

Comment: have you used proguard when export apk???

Comment: add your logcat errors

Comment: yes, I have used proguard